# Google Map API 3: renaming MapTypId

Tags: google-maps-api-3, dictionary, controls, panel

In my Map Control Panel, I would like to label the MapTypId 'Hybrid' to something more specific for my settings like 'Orthophoto'. I can't find any option to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to change map name. Look example below.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 zoom : 15,
 center : new google.maps.LatLng(43.439,39.914),
 mapTypeControlOptions : {
  mapTypeIds : ['hybrid']
 }
});
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
 this.mapTypes.hybrid.name = 'Orthophoto';
 this.setOptions({mapTypeControl:{}});
});
```

Last string i use to rebuild/redraw mapTypeControl.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implemented option to change the label, but you may create a custom mapType (e.g. a styledMapType )and apply the `HYBRID`-mapType when the custom mapType has been selected.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/BGQxj/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/BGQxj/)